# Windows Server 2012 prevent remote desktop account logging out after inactivity

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, timeout, logout, powershell-3.0

I've got a process that is running from Powershell on an Windows Server 2012 instance in AWS, however it is currently running under a user's account. The issue is that once the remote desktop connection closes for any reason, that account appears to get logged out after a certain amount of time.

The remote-desktop session closing after inactivity is completely fine - but how do I stop the account on the other side from logging out and killing the process?

Comment: Does the procedure exposed in [this article](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html) relate to your problem?

Comment: That might help - I'd rather not leave the remote computer unlocked though. Also, I've clarified, it's a process running from Powershell.